# Foreach binding object with array

Tags: knockout.js

How to iterate this object with array

```
var object = {description: 'test', array : [1,2,3]}
```

i tried

```
<div data-bind="foreach: object.array">
    <span>$data</span>
</div>
```

But i am getting no ouput. object is ko.observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that context `$data` appears to be just a text. Probably you want [text binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html) like:

```
<span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkdsuqax/1/)

Comment: tried that too, not working. I also tried having my array in a property named data.

Comment: @giannisf can you show what exactly you tried? I added link to jsfiddle where it works perfectly.

Comment: i don't have an array with entries but an object with property entries (named array).

Comment: @giannisf can you update your question with your view model and code how are you applying bindings? I am not quite understand what you are meaning, but I updated jsfiddle to look similar to code in your question. http://jsfiddle.net/bkdsuqax/1/ So you need to have a property on your view model but **var object** will declare local variable which wont be visible outside your view model scope (or whenever it defined).